# Effect of context sensitivity of propositions expressed in natural language on argument validity

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

On [page 34 of *Logic: The Laws of Truth*](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=wlL2GHt1gS8C&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=the+laws+of+truth+%22reads+the+first+two+lines+and+ben%22&source=bl&ots=ZzpBwS3-mS&sig=ACfU3U1U6XePZrAQD2fEfzaerBF9IpzpLA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFrPy-5Jj8AhWLXmwGHa8SDzoQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=%22reads%20the%20first%20two%20lines%20and%20ben%22&f=false), Smith uses the following example to illustrate how the context in which a natural language sentence is uttered can affect the proposition being expressed by that sentence, which in turn can affect the validity of an argument containing that proposition:

> ```
> I am short.
> If I am short, then I am not tall.
> Therefore, I am not tall.
> ```
>
> If Bob (who is short) reads the first two lines and Ben (who is tall) reads the last
> line, then the argument - sequence of propositions - that they express is not valid.
> Likewise, if Jane reads the first two lines when she is four (and short for her age) and
> then reads the last line when she is eighteen (and has become tall for her age) then the
> argument - sequence of propositions - that she expresses is not valid.

So, my understanding as to why this argument is invalid in the first scenario is that when Bob reads the first two lines, he is expressing the claims that *he* (Bob) is short and that if *he* is short, then *he* is not tall. And when Ben reads the last line, he is expressing the claim that *he* (Ben) is not tall. So, the argument effectively becomes:

**Bob** is short. 
If **Bob** is short, then **Bob** is not tall. 
Therefore, **Ben** is not tall.

The conclusion of this argument is not a logical consequence of its premises, therefore the argument is not valid.

**Is this what Smith means to convey with this example?** The reason I'm not sure if my explanation is correct is because Smith mentions Bob and Ben's actual heights (in the quote above, he says, *"Bob (who is short)...and Ben(who is tall)"*). **Why is this? What bearing do their actual heights have on the validity of the argument?** (Likewise in Jane's scenario.)

Comment: Yes the use of indexicals affects the validity of argumrnts.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA, but why might the speakers' actual heights be important? (By speakers, I mean Bob, Ben and Jane.)

Comment: Not very clear... A correct argument is: "Bob is short. Everything that is short is not tall. Therefore..." No indexicals at all.